# Flex with BlazeDS

Tags: database, apache-flex, blazeds

I am using flex with blazeDS and little confused. I have to show data in charts for a particular year (used combobox) for which data has taken from data base using java. Is it possible to store all data on page load in flex to reduce the time and without hitting database??? 
Please help....

Comment: Why not? Once you've retrieved a remote object, you can do anything you want with it, just like you would with any other object.